# Geometry Tools: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am in the process of learning Earth Engine by following the tutorial for [F2.1: Interpreting an Image: Classification, Section 1 - Supervised Classification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UCB900oCdJERca-2WUeDlCu52MjPKJxETJ_jJcLM0bM/edit#heading=h.n4sgfb1l8aik). I am able to bring in the cloud free image, but unable to add the 25 features per classification by using the "Geometry Imports > Add Marker" option. I have set the 'Import as" to "FeatureCollection" and the class set to 0 (zero) under Properties. When I click more than once on the image, I receive "`Maximum call stack size exceeded"` error in the Console window. The code and geometry imports are directly from the Earth Engine book (https://www.eefabook.org/go-to-the-book.html).

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it?

```
// Create an Earth Engine Point object over Milan.
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([9.453, 45.424]);

// Filter the Landsat 8 collection and select the least cloudy image.
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(pt)
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first();

// Center the map on that image.
Map.centerObject(landsat, 8);

// Add Landsat image to the map.
var visParams = {
    bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
    min: 7000,
    max: 12000
};

Map.addLayer(landsat, visParams, 'Landsat 8 image');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question so that both the code and error are presented as text. This allows others to reproduce your issue and allows other with the same issue to find your Question.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Please include a link to your script in the EE Code Editor. (Use the `Get Link` button).